# Create new column in pands with groupby and max(date)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Customer':  ['99999', '99999', '99999', '88888', '88888', '88888'],
        'Date': ['2019-04-12', '2019-05-11','2020-05-12', '2019-06-06', '2019-04-04', '2020-05-05'],
        'Value': ['4','4','9','5','6','9']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Customer','Date','Value'])
```

How can I create a new column "LastValue" with the latest Value grouped by Customer and the max(date). So my final output should looks like this:

```
    Customer    Date    Value   LastValue
0   99999       2019-04-12  4   9
1   99999       2019-05-11  4   9
2   99999       2020-05-12  9   9
3   88888       2019-06-06  5   9
4   88888       2019-04-04  6   9
5   88888       2020-05-05  9   9
```

I'm new in python, in R i would use something like this:

```
 df %>% group_by(Customer) %>% filter(Date== max(Date)) %>% mutate(LastValue = Value)
```

Update:

With the solution of @jezrael I have a little bug:

When I use a df like this:

```
  import pandas as pd

data = {'Customer':  ['99999', '99999', '99999',
                      '99999', '99999', '99999',
                      '99999', '99999', '99999',
                      '99999', '99999', '99999','99999',
                      '88888', '88888', '88888'],
        'OtherValue':  ['88888', '88888', '88888',
                        '88888', '88888', '88888',
                        '88888', '88888', '88888',
                        '88888', '88888', '88888',
                        '88888', '88888', '88888',
                        '88888'],
        'Date': ['2019-06-27',
                    '2019-06-05',
                    '2019-05-28',
                    '2019-06-04',
                    '2019-06-04',
                    '2019-06-17',
                    '2019-01-01',
                    '2019-06-07',
                    '2019-06-19',
                    '2019-03-12',
                    '2019-04-16',
                    '2019-06-13',
                    '2019-02-05',
                    '2019-06-06', 
                    '2019-04-04', 
                    '2020-05-05'],
        'Value': ['5','3','3',
                  '3','2','2',
                '2','1','1',
                 '1','1','1',
                 '1','1','1','2']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Customer','OtherValue','Date','Value'])
```

I get with the solution following output:

```
       Customer OtherValue       Date Value LastValue NewColumn
6     99999      88888 2019-01-01     2         5         1
12    99999      88888 2019-02-05     1         5         1
9     99999      88888 2019-03-12     1         5         1
10    99999      88888 2019-04-16     1         5         1
2     99999      88888 2019-05-28     3         5         1
3     99999      88888 2019-06-04     3         5         1
4     99999      88888 2019-06-04     2         5         1
1     99999      88888 2019-06-05     3         5         1
7     99999      88888 2019-06-07     1         5         1
11    99999      88888 2019-06-13     1         5         1
5     99999      88888 2019-06-17     2         5         1
8     99999      88888 2019-06-19     1         5         1
0     99999      88888 2019-06-27     5         5         1
14    88888      88888 2019-04-04     1         2         1
13    88888      88888 2019-06-06     1         2         1
15    88888      88888 2020-05-05     2         2         1
```

But with customer 99999 and Othervalue 88888 the NewColumn should be 3 because it is the next nearest value to 5 and it exists >=2 times in the Value column by the group(Customer, Othervalue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for index value by maximum `Date`, so converted column `Value` to index in first step:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['LastValue'] = (df.set_index('Value')
                     .groupby('Customer')['Date']
                     .transform('idxmax')
                     .to_numpy())
print (df)
  Customer       Date Value LastValue
0    99999 2019-04-12     4         9
1    99999 2019-05-11     4         9
2    99999 2020-05-12     9         9
3    88888 2019-06-06     5         9
4    88888 2019-04-04     6         9
5    88888 2020-05-05     9         9
```

Another idea better is sorting by `Customer` and `Date`, so then is possible use last value of `Value` column:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df = df.sort_values(['Customer','OtherValue', 'Value'], ascending=[False, True, True])
df['LastValue'] = df.groupby('Customer')['Value'].transform('last')
print (df)

m2 = df.duplicated(subset=['Customer','OtherValue', 'Value'], keep=False)
#always last, so not necessary test
df['NewColumn'] = (df['Value'].where(m2)
                              .groupby([df['Customer'], df['OtherValue']])
                              .transform('last'))
print (df)
   Customer OtherValue       Date Value LastValue NewColumn
7     99999      88888 2019-06-07     1         5         3
8     99999      88888 2019-06-19     1         5         3
9     99999      88888 2019-03-12     1         5         3
10    99999      88888 2019-04-16     1         5         3
11    99999      88888 2019-06-13     1         5         3
12    99999      88888 2019-02-05     1         5         3
4     99999      88888 2019-06-04     2         5         3
5     99999      88888 2019-06-17     2         5         3
6     99999      88888 2019-01-01     2         5         3
1     99999      88888 2019-06-05     3         5         3
2     99999      88888 2019-05-28     3         5         3
3     99999      88888 2019-06-04     3         5         3
0     99999      88888 2019-06-27     5         5         3
13    88888      88888 2019-06-06     1         2         1
14    88888      88888 2019-04-04     1         2         1
15    88888      88888 2020-05-05     2         2         1
```

Comment: kindly check ur result. it is different from OP's expected output

Comment: @jezrael: I have a little bug in your solution. I update my post with your solution and the bug.

Comment: @jezrael: because it should be the next nearest value to the LastValue if this does not exists 2 times or more in the value column.

Comment: @Tim1234 - I add output and last value is `1`, because `1` is duplicated and also lower like `3`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213401/discussion-between-tim1234-and-jezrael).

Comment: @ jezrael is it possible that you come to chat again :)

Comment: @jezrael: I fixed the problem now. I split the solutions into two steps and merge the final result at the end. The sorting was the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Without `groupby`, you can do it with `sort_value`, `mask` with a lambda checking for where the Customer change, `bfill` and thanks to index alignment.

```
df['LastValue'] = df.sort_values(['Customer','Date'])\
                    .mask(lambda x: x['Customer'].eq(x['Customer'].shift(-1)))['Value']\
                    .bfill()
print (df)
  Customer        Date Value LastValue
0    99999  2019-04-12     4         9
1    99999  2019-05-11     4         9
2    99999  2020-05-12     9         9
3    88888  2019-06-06     5         9
4    88888  2019-04-04     6         9
5    88888  2020-05-05     9         9
```

Comment: this works good. is it possible to add a secon value like OtherValue above?

Comment: @Tim1234 Not sure to understand where the column OtherValue comes in the process here